# Clean URL support in MAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I am trying to setup a website on my Mac using MAMP. I put my website content into a folder under

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/positweb

"positweb" containins index.php which tries this redirect:

```
header("Location: web/main");
```

Along index.php I have .htaccess file, which came with the website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have also enabled "AllowOverride All" inside

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/Library/htdocs">
```

element in both httpd.conf and httpd-std.conf files.

Now, my problem is that these redirects don't work on my setup. Chrome says that the link "http://localhost/positweb/web/main" is broken, Firefox says that index.php is not found.

All of the php/.htaccess files are exact copies of a working version of the site. I tried playing around with Apache settings like I described above, but with no luck, and now I don't know what else to try.

My MAMP version is 1.9.5.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: After looking through php scripts that came with the website, it seems that all .htaccess is meant to redirect *all* urls over to index.php, which in turn makes a call to `header("Location: web/main");` . The thing is, there is no 'main' directory in the scripts folder, there is however web.php script, and judging by the content of that script, it is meant to capture `web/main` header, parse out the token that comes after 'web/' and take action based on what that token is (the token being 'main' in my case). (cont...)

Comment: ... So if I for example replace header(...) call described above with something like `header("Location: web.php")` , then it loads web.php, but now `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` contains no tokens, so the script does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `base_url` in the bootstrap.php from `/` to `/positweb`

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried doing that, but it just enters infinite loop trying to redirect me to something like: `http://localhost/positweb/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/web/main`

Comment: That's because the redirect you set up at the top of index.php just redirects to itself. remove `header("Location: web/main");` and use a route if necessary

Answer (score 0):

And make sure you've got `FollowSymLinks` turned on in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: I did have `Options All` set for directory `<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">` , which I understand includes FollowSymLinks, I tried including that flag explicitly, but with no luck.